# Is a custom X509Store automatically delete if is empty?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, x509certificate2

I have some code that create a custom store to test some certificate related operation, how can I be sure that the store is empty and is removed from the system? I cannot see it in the Certificate Manager.

Example:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("HelloWorld", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
// add and remove some store
// some operations etc.
store.Close();
store.Dispose();
```

The `Close` and `Dispose` just clean up the resource allocation in the code, but I don't think it actually deletes it off the drive. I looked around and it doesn't seem like there is a way to "delete the store".

Can I assumed that Windows would automatically remove an empty X509Store? If not, how can I clean it up?

Comment: What flags are you using in the call to `store.Open`

Comment: Updated, is `OpenFlags.ReadWrite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no managed way to delete the store. You need to p/invoke [CertUnregisterPhysicalStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certunregisterphysicalstore) native function.

Comment: Is it not `CertUnregisterSystemStore` that needs to be called?

Comment: You can try both.